# need to aply a different style sheet for a specific page template

Tags: themes

I am working with twenty fourteen theme.
I want to customize the full-width template for my needs, to make it wider on specific pages.
so I copied it into a sub folder in my child theme.

how do I embed styling that will affect this template ONLY?

tried this, but it doesnt work: http://www.transformationpowertools.com/wordpress/real-full-width-page-template-twentyfourteen

p.s: I am not a developer :(

Comment: what is the sub-folder name, and what is the file name of the full width page template? what CSS class have you tried to use?

Comment: sub-folder, file name: twentyfourteen-child/page-templates/real-full-width.php

CSS:

`.site {
max-width: 100%;
}

.site-header {
max-width: 100%;
}

.site-content .entry-header,
.site-content .entry-content,
.site-content .entry-summary,
.site-content .entry-meta,
.page-content {
max-width: 80%;
}

.comments-area {
margin: 48px auto;
max-width: 80%;
padding: 0 10px;
}
.site-content .entry-meta {
max-width:100%;
}
.primary-navigation {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 65px;
}
.hentry {
    max-width: 930px;
}`

Comment: couldnt paste the code properly, sorry. back-ticks didnt work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I embed styling that will affect this template only?

The trick is to hook into [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/). This allows us to see which template is being applied to a page.

Suppose we have a template with a basename of 'full-width.php'. Inside our template_include callback, we can conditionally enqueue a CSS style only when the template is full width.

```
function wpse_258048_template_include( $template ) {
  if( 'full-width.php' === basename( $template ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'full-width', PATH_TO . '/full-width.css' );
  }
  return $template;
}
add_action( 'template_include', 'wpse_258048_template_include', 1000, 1 );
```

Comment: so I figured it out thanks to http://dobsondev.com/2015/06/05/conditionally-enqueue-stylesheet-into-wordpress-for-certain-page/
I added this code to functions.php and it works great. looks very similar to your solution:
`
function register_foundation_style() {
  if ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/full-width.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'full-width', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/full-width.css' );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_foundation_style' );
`

Answer (score 0):

```
function register_foundation_style() {
  if ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/full-width.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'full-width', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/full-width.css' );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_foundation_style' );
```